# A probably simple combinatorics question

Tags: combinatorics

I've faced the following problem, it comes from physics actually, but the precise details are of no importance. Consider a set $\{x_{n}\}_{n=1, ..., N}$. We construct the following function
$$F(\{x_{n}\}_{n=1, ..., N}, \{q_{m}\}_{m=1, ..., M})=\sum_{n_{1}=1}^{N}...\sum_{n_{M}=1}^{N}\exp\Bigg(-i\sum_{m=1}^{M}q_{m}x_{n_{m}}\Bigg).$$
The question is as follows: what is the number of terms in the series above such that the number $S\in\{0, ..., M\}$ of $x_{n_{m}}$s in the exponent are equal to one another?

For example for $M=1$ there are $N$ terms with one $x$ equal to itself. for $M=2$ we have $N$ terms with both $x$ being equal and $N(N-1)$ terms with unequal $x$, for $M=3$ we have $N$ terms with all $3$ $x$ being the same, $3N(N-1)$ terms (if I'm correct) with $2$ $x$ equal and not equal to the third, and $N(N-1)(N-2)$ terms with distinct $x$, etc. Is there a general formula in terms of $N$ and $M$ for this thing?

PS Sorry if I was not being clear enough, I'm not versed in these things.

Update: I have a feeling that the number of terms with two of $x$s being equal is given by
$$\frac{1}{2}M(M-1)N(N-1), \ M=1, 2, ...$$

Comment: what do you mean with : "such that the number S∈{1,...,M} of $x_{n_m}$s in the exponent are equal to one another" ? we want some numbers to be equal to each other I'm assuming. Could you say which are the numbers that we want to be equal to each other? Would it be possible to add a version of the problem without the stuff that doesn't matter?

Comment: @Yorch Each $x_{n_{m}}$ for $n_{m}=1, ..., N$ and $m=1, ..., M$ can take on values $\{x_{1}, ..., x_{N}\}$. how many terms have all $x$ equal? this means $x_{n_{1}}=x_{n_{2}}=...=x_{n_{M}}$, the clear answer is $N$. How many terms do we have such that all $x$ are distinct? it is N(N-1)(N-2)....(N-M+1). In general, how many terms are there such at $S=0, 1, ..., M$ out of all $x$ are equal?

Comment: are equal to what, to at least one other term?

Comment: Do you want to separate them depending on how many distinct $x_{n_m}$ appear?

Comment: It is not the terms that have to be equal but the $x_{n_{m}}$s, that is the only thing that matters. they take values in the same set, so in this sum there are many distinct terms where say 3 of xs are equal

Comment: Precisely! depending on how many distinct I have!

Comment: am I correct that if $N<M$ then the answer is $0$ for $S>n$ ?

Comment: You mean for $S>N$? then yes. but $N$ is supposed to eventually be send to $\infty$, so it is not an issue=)

Answer (score 1):

We have functions  $\{1,\dots,M\} \rightarrow \{1,\dots,N\}$ and for each $S\in \{1,\dots,M\}$ you want to know how many such functions take on exactly $S$ distinct values.

This is one of the problems in the twelvefold way and the answer is given by $\binom{N}{S}{ M \brace S }S!$ where the curly brackets are stirling coefficients of the second kind.

In particular when $S=1$ we get $\binom{N}{1}{ M \brace 1 } 1! = N\times 1 \times 1 = N$.

When $S>N$ we get $\binom{N}{S}{M \brace S} S! = 0 \times {M \brace S} S! = 0$

when $S=2$ we get $\binom{N}{2}{M \brace 2} 2!= N(N-1)(\frac{2^{M}-2}{2})$

When $S=M$ and $N\geq M$ we get $\binom{N}{M}{ M \brace M} M! = N(N-1)\dots(N-M+1)$

Comment: let me know if this isn't what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is equivalent to asking the expected number of duplicates, triplicates, etc. from a series of random draws. Does this answer your question, then?

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57347/expected-number-of-duplicates-triplicates-etc-when-drawing-with-replacement

Comment: Welcome to MSE! This should really be a comment, not an answer. It's pretty short, and expects OP to go somewhere else. If you explained _why_ OP's question is equivalent to the answer you describe, then link the question and give a quick summary of the results (for instance, just say the closed form formula that answers OP's question) that would be better. But since you've linked something on stats, why not include the whole argument so that future MSE users have this on record at MSE? It looks like the argument in your link is fairly short

Comment: Not really, sorry.